# approximate the variance/entropy of the minimum of correlated normal

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a random vector following a high dimension normal distribution. In my case, the number of components of the vector is not very large,  say n=10.

Now I want to approximate the distribution/variance/entropy of the minimum of all the components. Is there any way to do so? Thank you!

Comment: This might be helpful http://www.research.ibm.com/people/c/chandu/pubs/2013/todaes13.pdf

Comment: ...and also this http://mathoverflow.net/questions/63490/maximum-of-gaussian-random-variables

Comment: Thank you. But my assumption is that all the components are of non-zero mean. So I think the background is different. I am reading the first paper to see if I can find something helpful.